# Glide round corners when I load image

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I need to convert `byte[]` to Bitmap and put it in `ImageView`.
I've seen that Glide do it and so I've implemented this code in `onBindViewHolder():`

```
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(aircraft.getPhoto()) //this returns byte[]
            .override(1280,1280)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(mHolder.imgPic);
```

and this is the layout of the single cardView:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/aircraft"
                android:id="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pic"

                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pic" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

when Glide loads image, I see rounded border, like this:
[image]

why does it gives me round black borders?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting the background color of the CardView or ImageView to transparent?

Comment: try to use fitCenter() --> insted of centerCrop ().......Glide.with(context).load(url).fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(img);

Comment: tried both solutions, both does not solve the issue

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @r3dm4n i don't find solution of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the backgrounds as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                ......
                    >
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/aircraft"
               android:id="@+id/pic"
               android:background="#fff"
               .....    
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```